# SQL issue with RIGHT JOINS

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, right-join

The following SQL query does exactly what it should do, but I don't know how to change it so it does what I **need** it to do.

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS comment_id, a.parent_comment_id, a.user_id, a.pid, a.comment, a.blocked_at, a.blocked_by, a.created_at, a.updated_at,
    b.name, b.is_moderator, COUNT(IF(d.type = 1, 1, NULL)) AS a_count, COUNT(IF(d.type = 2, 1, NULL)) AS b_count
FROM 
    comments AS a
RIGHT JOIN 
    users AS b ON b.id = a.user_id
RIGHT JOIN 
    node_user AS c ON c.user = b.id
RIGHT JOIN 
    nodes AS d ON d.id = c.node
WHERE 
    a.pid = 999
GROUP BY
    comment_id
ORDER BY
    a.created_at ASC
```

It gets all comments belonging to a specific `pid`, it then `RIGHT JOINS` additional user data like `name` and `is_moderator`, then `RIGHT JOINS` any (so called) nodes including additional data based on the `user id` and `node id`. As seen in the `SELECT`, I count the nodes based on their type.

This works great for users that have any `nodes` attached to their accounts. But users who don't have any, so whose `id` doesn't exist in the `node_user` and `nodes` tables, won't be shown in the query results.

**So my question:**

How can I make it so that even users who don't have any `nodes`, are still shown in the query results but with an `a_count` and `b_count` of `0` or `NULL`.

Comment: Aren't you implying an inner join here with a filter on comments?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Probably, could you please eloborate?

Comment: Although you are using right joins (or left if you wish), you have a filter on comments which could be null because of (right ot left) joins. But since you are explicitly sayin it should be 999, you are saying you in fact meant inner join.

Comment: Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right/left [sic] table column to be not NULL after a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want *left join*s not *right join*s.  You also want to fix your table aliases so they are meaningful:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = c.user_id LEFT JOIN
     node_user nu
     ON nu.user = u.id LEFT JOIN
     nodes n
     ON n.id = nu.node
WHERE c.pid = 999
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.created_at ASC;
```

This keeps everything in the *first* table, regardless of whether or not rows match in the subsequent tables.  That appears to be what you want.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, but seems I forgot one thing in my first post: I also need to check whether all the count `a_count` and `b_count` have an `active = 1`. But I suppose that's a matter of changing `COUNT(IF(d.type = 1, 1, NULL)) AS a_count` to `COUNT(IF(d.type = 1 AND d.active = 1, 1, NULL)) AS a_count`, right?

Comment: @luikstruik . . . Something like that should do what you want.